# Calculate the Sum of the Bound field Column values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have a GridView which consists of Five Bound Field Column Such as AttributeName, Tax Percentage, Reference Amount, Sign, Tax Amount.

The GridView may have two rows or three rows or sometimes there would be no rows in the GridView.

Here I want to calculate the TaxAmount of all the rows in the GridView and I want to display the Total Tax amount into a Label.

I know how to do this in C#. But here, I want to do this in the Client Side itself using JavaScript.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I changed the BoundField Column to TemplateField.

The answer for the above Question is

```
 function CalculateTax()
 {
    var taxgrid = document.getElementById('<%=gvAttribute.ClientID %>');
    var taxip = taxgrid.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var taxamount = 0*1;

    for(i = 0; i < taxip.length; i++)
    {
       var tax = taxip[i].value;            
       taxamount = parseFloat(taxamount) + parseFloat(tax);
    }
    document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').innerText = taxamount.toFixed(2)+ "/-";            
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use "TemplateColumn" instead of "BoundColumn".

Comment: I am not familiar in JavaScript. Ok. If I changed it to Template Field then How to Calculate?